# Link Google Ads BiqQuery data to GA BigQuery Session Data

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

Is it possible to link Google Ads BiqQuery data to GA BigQuery Session Data?
By this is there a link between the data at all i.e. a key? OR something that is relational?

The idea is to work out spend against revenue generated from the Google Ads data.

Thanks